# WPF: Integer CLR property not recognized or is not accessible from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, clr, dependency-properties

I have a custom control in WPF. I added two plain CLR property, that look like this:

```
private int _ChordFrom = 0;
public int ChordFrom
{
    get { return _ChordFrom; }
    set { _ChordFrom = value; }
}

private int _ChordTo = 0;
public int ChordTo
{
    get { return _ChordTo; }
    set { _ChordTo = value; }
}
```

I use plain CLR properties, because I don't want to bind these properties to any other dependency. I just want to set the values inside XAML, when the control is instantiated.

Inside XAML the properties are found by intellisense, but when building the project I get the error:

**"The member "ChordFrom" is not recognized or is not accessible."
"The member "ChordTo" is not recognized or is not accessible."**

The XAML code looks like this:

```
<TabItem Header="CHORDS I">
    <Grid x:Name="_gridChords_1" Background="AliceBlue">
        <mg:MidiChordGrid x:Name="gridMidiChordGrid_1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  ChordFrom="0" ChordTo="7"/>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

There are three things, I wonder about:

- Why does Intellisense offers me the the properties inside XAML, if
  they are not accessible?
- If I close all XAML windows, rebuild the project, the errors
  disappear.
- Even if can build the project without any errors, the properties are
  not set.

**ANSWER | ANSWER | ANSWER | ANSWER | ANSWER | ANSWER | ANSWER**

Thanks for all the answers, but the solution/error was inside my code. I forgot to update my grid after setting these two CLR properties. Sorry for this.

**But here some facts you may want to know:**

- You can use and set plain CLR properties inside WPF XAML. I checked it out and the properties are set from XAML
- The error "not recognized or is not accessible" seems to be a VS bug, because the project is buildable
- If you close the XAML files inside VS there will be no build errors anymore

To me, using plain CLR properties is the best solution at this point, because the values I pass to the control are hardcoded for every instance of the control and they do not change at runtime. Of course I would want to use attached DPs, if the values changed at runtime, which they don't.

Thank for your quick answers, but it in the end it was a my fault.

Comment: Thank you Piotr. I have tested this with dependency properties and I got the same error. I am working on this since yesterday. I tried normal DP, attached DP and now plain CLR properties.

Comment: Actually you can use normal property in xaml if you are not using binding like this so that's not the problem

Comment: If I close all XAML windows, rebuild the project, the errors disappear. => this mean it's actually a designer error not actually a build error, what happen if you try to run it?

Comment: If I run it, the properties are not set.

Comment: Also could you give the definition of the class MidiChordGrid ?

Comment: Can you check that MidiChordGrid  is not private?

Comment: Also could you try adding a breakpoint in the setter of ChordTo to check that it is really not called

Comment: Just to check I tried the exact same code just by creating a MidiChordGrid  class inheriting button and it was working so the problem is not in the code you gave

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers. I will now figure out, what I can do with your answers and hints.

Comment: I answered the question in my starting post. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

I am just confirming that this appears to be a visual studio bug as mentioned in the question.
I added a couple properties to a control and spent an hour trying to figure out why it would not build.  After reading the above post I simply closed the xaml file, clicked build and it built successfully.
Using VS 2013 community sp 4.

Comment: You just saved an hour of mine. Thanks!